# Tomcat/TomEE: TomEE GUI page 404 error

Tags: tomcat, web, tomcat7, apache-tomee

I recently installed "apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.2" on to a "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (6.6).

I am able to access the Tomcat home page by accessing x.x.x.x:8080 and via this, I am able to access the "Server Status", "Manager App" and "Host Manager" pages. However, when I go to access the "TomEE GUI" page, I receive an "Error 404: description The requested resource is not available." page.

From what I can see Tomee is running as when I access the "Manage App" page, "/tomee" is there and it's running state is true.

I'm new to TomEE so there may be a step which I have missed/completed incorrectly. So any help on how I can get this working would be great.

I'm not sure what code is relevant to this issue, so please tell me what configuration would be helpful and I'll post it.

Comment: Question: Do I need to have anything deployed before I can access this page? Is there not a default page that is accessed when first installed? As I don't currently have anything deployed, so I wondered if this could be it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In TomEE 1.7.2 the webapps/tomee folder is missing, this is why 404 error occurs. I don't know if it is a bug or it is intentional. (In 1.7.1 webapps/tomee folder is still there.)

But it is actually not so important. This page only says that "Your server is fully installed". I think that it is useful only when you install a drop-in WAR TomEE in a Tomcat and so you can check if it is installed successfully.

But when you download and use a native TomEE this check does not count.

Just deploy your applicaton and enjoy it!

(However if you still want TomEE GUI, download version 1.7.1 and copy the tomee folder in the webapps folder into the webapps folder of 1.7.2.)

Answer (score 7):

Apparently GUI part of TomEE has been moved to a new project, TomEE WebAccess which can be downloaded separately on the download page, http://tomee.apache.org/downloads.html, and dropped into the webapps folder.

Source: (http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/TomEE-GUI-doesnt-come-up-tt4673008.html#a4673466)

It's missing a fancy UI (and documentation) but does let you run Groovy or Javascript on the admin to get some interesting info.

On the list, Thiago posted this Groovy example to get the REST endpoints:

```
import org.apache.openejb.loader.SystemInstance 
import org.apache.openejb.server.rest.RsRegistry 
import org.apache.openejb.monitoring.LocalMBeanServer 

def mbeanServer = LocalMBeanServer.get() 
def registry = SystemInstance.get().getComponent(RsRegistry) 
registry.listeners.each { key, listener -> 
  listener.jmxNames.each { name -> 
    mbeanServer.getAttribute(name, 'operations').values().each { ops -> 
      ops.compositeType.keySet().each { 
        println(it) 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make the TomEE Gui link on the TomEE start page work, you have to rename tomee-webaccess-7.0.x.war to tomee.war and give your admin user the tomee-admin role.

```
<user username="tomcat" password=".." roles="manager-gui,tomee-admin"/>
```

Anyway, there is not much to see with this app.